# Console output for function with multiple optional arguments

Tags: javascript

Console output for function with multiple arguments

I have this class method:

```
searchForProduct({productName, manufacturer, seller}, itemsPerPage = 20, onlyAvailable = true) {
    console.log(Searching for...) // Here's what is my question about
    //do stuff
}
```

How can I print out all arguments that I'm passing to the method?

What a want to achieve is:

```
searchForProduct({productName: laptop});

// Output:
"Searching for productName: 'laptop'"

// or

searchForProduct({productName: "laptop", manufacturer: "Dell"});

// Output:
"Searching for productName: 'laptop', manufacturer: 'Dell'"
```

And so on...

Also (if it's possible with any approach that will be proposed) I don't want to print out default `itemsPerPage` and `onlyAvailable` even if it will be passed to the method.

**UPD:**

Wow, I was not expecting this amount of such neat approaches in the answers. 
However I should admit that I'm not allowed to change this function. Basically I just need to add this output form my personal needs since changing this method will "break everything".

I apologize for time that you took to propose passing object instead of destructed arguments. I'll upvote your answers anyway

**UPD2:**

I tried a couple of suggestion but still didn't achieved the perfect result:

```
searchForProduct({productName, manufacturer, seller}, itemsPerPage = 20, onlyAvailable = true) {
    function buildString({firstArgument, secondArgument, thirdArgument}) {
        return {
            productName: (firstArgument !== undefined) ? firstArgument : "",
            manufacturer: (secondArgument !== undefined) ? secondArgument : "",
            seller: (thirdArgument !== undefined) ? thirdArgument : ""
        }
    }
    const searchString = buildString({productName, manufacturer, seller})
    const displayStr = Object.entries(searchString)
    .map(([key, val]) => key + ': ' + val)
    .join(', ');
    console.log('Searching for', displayStr);
    //do stuff
}
```

The `buildString` function is super ugly but it works without changing the original function.

However I have faced an issue when not all arguments are passed

It will look like:

```
"Searching for productName: "laptop", manufacturer: "Dell", seller: undefined
```

I tried:

```
function buildString({firstArgument, secondArgument, thirdArgument}) {
        return {
            productName: (firstArgument !== undefined) ? firstArgument : delete productName,
            manufacturer: (secondArgument !== undefined) ? secondArgument : delete manufacturer,
            seller: (thirdArgument !== undefined) ? thirdArgument : delete seller
        }
    }
```

But this gives me:

```
"Searching for productName: "laptop", manufacturer: "Dell", seller: true
```

According to MDN:

> When trying to delete a property that does  not exist, true is
>   returned

However property does exist - it's value does not. So what I tried to above is to delete the object key if it does not have a value.
Currently no success

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't destructure the first argument - instead, stringify it or iterate over its entries to extract its keys and values:

```js
const searchForProduct = (obj) => {
  console.log('Searching for', JSON.stringify(obj));
};
searchForProduct({productName: 'laptop'});
searchForProduct({productName: "laptop", manufacturer: "Dell"});
```

```js
const searchForProduct = (obj) => {
  const displayStr = Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => key + ': ' + val)
    .join(', ');
  console.log('Searching for', displayStr);
};
searchForProduct({productName: 'laptop'});
searchForProduct({productName: "laptop", manufacturer: "Dell"});
```

You can also use a wrapper function that does the same thing:

```js
const searchForProductWrapper = (obj, itemsPerPage = 20, onlyAvailable = true) => {
  const displayStr = Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => key + ': ' + val)
    .join(', ');
  console.log('Searching for', displayStr);
  searchForProduct(obj, itemsPerPage, onlyAvailable);
};
const searchForProduct = (obj, itemsPerPage, onlyAvailable) => {
  console.log('true searchForProduct', obj, itemsPerPage, onlyAvailable);
};
searchForProductWrapper({productName: 'laptop'}, 10);
searchForProductWrapper({productName: "laptop", manufacturer: "Dell"});
```

Comment: I have updated the question a little bit to make some clarifications. However can I somehow maybe store arguments in to the object and use your second approach (Since I can't change the current approach of passing the arguments)?

Comment: If you aren't allowed to change the function, then... changing the function to check and log stuff won't be possible regardless..?

Comment: Unless you're able to re-define the function and overwrite it with your own implementation, or something like that, but that's weird

Comment: By "changing the function" I mean changing the way how it works now (by accepting 3 arguments). But I can make wrapper around it and call the "original" function inside. But I'm not sure how I will handle cases when only one parameter is passed... I mean if I will pass `obj` how will I know does this object contains only `productName` or both  `productName` and `manufacturer`... (I need to know it because I need to know what should I pass to the "original" function)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I print out all arguments that I'm passing to the method?

Its more like you would like to see object properties of first argument

```js
function searchForProduct(data, itemsPerPage = 20, onlyAvailable = true) {
  console.log(`Searching for ${JSON.stringify(Object.entries(data))}`)
}

criteria = {
  productName: '',
  manufacturer: ''
}

searchForProduct(criteria)
```